# Hadoop Wordcount program stuck at “running job”

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I Installed and Set Up a 7-Node Hadoop(3.3.1) Cluster.  But When I run the Hadoop word count program the program is stuck at "Running job".

```
root@hadoop-master:~# bash run-wordcount.sh
2022-07-31 07:00:21,038 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2022-07-31 07:00:21,494 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1659250805263_0001
2022-07-31 07:00:21,927 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 2
2022-07-31 07:00:22,269 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
2022-07-31 07:00:22,400 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1659250805263_0001
2022-07-31 07:00:22,400 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2022-07-31 07:00:22,577 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2022-07-31 07:00:22,578 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2022-07-31 07:00:23,067 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1659250805263_0001
2022-07-31 07:00:23,108 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1659250805263_0001/
2022-07-31 07:00:23,109 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1659250805263_0001
```

[image]

[image]

my config is following

```
3 VM ==> 24Core,  128G RAM , 2T SSD  
     1 VM for name node
     2 VM for data node(run with 3 docker containers)
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoop-master</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
 <!--  Appoint  MapReduce  The program runs in  Yarn  On  -->
  <property>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
   <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

 <property>
   <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

What do I need to do to solve this problem? Please help

Comment: `2022-07-31 07:00:23,108 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1659250805263_0001/` well what does that say?

Comment: What do you see in the logs? From the RM screenshot, it says that job has been stuck in the accepted state and the GPU count is -1. It can be due to multiple reasons that your job is stuck in accepted state, maybe you dont have enough configured memory to allocate to your map task, may be services are in down state (check for any alerts). I am not sure which hadoop distribution you are using CDH or apache hadoop, you may check memory configurations. Please follow this link https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/yarn-reference/topics/yarn-configure-memory-settings.html